# Interceptor is not invoking and not visible (in logs, during deployments nothing see)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, wildfly, interceptor

I have a classes:

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.interceptor.AroundInvoke;
import javax.interceptor.InvocationContext;

public class AccessReportInterceptor {
    private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(AccessReportInterceptor.class);    

    @Inject
    private AccessReportManager accessReportManager;

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object intercept(InvocationContext context) throws Exception {
        log.info("invoked");
        return context.proceed();
    }
}

@Stateless
@Remote(ActionTypeHandlerRemote.class)
public class ActionTypeHandler implements ActionTypeHandlerRemote{
 @EJB protected DataManager dataManager;
 @Interceptors({AccessReportInterceptor.class})
    private void persistNewUser(User newUser){
        logger.info("Persisting new user: " + newUser.getLogin());
        logger.info("For : " + newUser.getName());
        newUser.setCreateTime(new Date());
        dataManager.persist(newUser);
    }

    @Interceptors({AccessReportInterceptor.class})
    private void mergeUser(User user){
        logger.info("Merging user with id: " + user.getLogin());
        user.setCreateTime(new Date());
        dataManager.merge(user);
    }
}
```

And when i invoked method persistNewUser or mergeUser then should (before invoke this methods) be started interceptor.

It seems that it ignores the Interceptor.

Why this not working ? What I am doing wrong?

Comment: How are you invoking those private methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make your methods public,private methods will not be intercepted.